# Whats the best way to embed a video from Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, video, embed

I am trying to show a video that's returned from Facebook's Graph Api.  I have the source of the video which is either a YouTube video, Vimeo video, Facebook Video, or any other type of video that is posted to the news feed.

My $facebookdata returns this:

```
[source] => http://www.youtube.com/v/PwD4t9gcLb4?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1
```

I've been setting the value of SOURCE to **$status_video_embed** like so:

```
$status_video_embed = str_replace("autoplay=1", "autoplay=0", $data['source']);
```

Also, you can see I am replacing the autoplay to 0 if it exists.

I've been embedding the videos to be displayed like this:

```
echo '<iframe src="' . $status_video_embed . '" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="350" height="197"></iframe>';
```

This works but I am running into a few problems.  First, if it's any video other than a Facebook video it plays fine, but I can't make it fullscreen.  I am assuming this is because it's embedding in an iFrame.  Second problem is with Facebook uploaded videos, they autoplay, and I can't figure out how to prevent autoplay with those videos.

The second approach I've taken is this:

```
echo '<object width="350" height="197" ><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />';
echo '<param name="movie" value="' . $status_video_embed . '" />';
echo '<embed src="' . $status_video_embed . '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="350" height="197"></embed>';
echo '</object>';
```

This displays the videos - except they take forever to load and display - it prevents the facebook videos from autoplaying, but now, when I click play on any video, nothing happens.  No controls through the embedded video works.

Does anyone have any idea what the best way to embed a video is in this method?  I am given the source to the video from the returned array.

I hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you just develop your own player in HTML5, And parse the video page for the URL??